# Security of an authentication algorithm

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am making a little script in python, in which a client has to authenticates to the server. The idea is that an attacker cannot authenticate himself by listening to the network, without knowing the password.
Despite any good practices, I am trying to make my own secure authentication (it is only for personal use).

In my current algorithm, the client and the server share :

- the password that authenticates the client
- an encryption key
- the encryption algorithm (AES with pycrypto)

It works as follows :

- The server generates a token
- The server encrypts the token
- The encrypted token is sent to the client
- The client decrypts the token
- The client encrypts the set (password + token)
- The encrypted set (password + token) is sent to the server
- The server decrypts (password + token)
- If the received information corresponds to the shared password and the token sent by the server, then the client is successfully authenticated.

In this algorithm, the client and the server share 2 secrets : the password and the encryption key.

I am wondering if it would be secure to do like this :

- The server generates a token
- The server sends the token to the client (in plain text)
- The client encrypts the token, and returns it to the server
- If the decrypted token is correct, the client is successfully authenticated.

In this case, the server and the client share only one secret (the encryption key). From my (small) knowledge of AES, I think that an attacker should not be able to guess the key with the token and the encrypted token, nor to guess the encrypted token without owning the key.

So my questions are: do you see any flaws in my algorithms? Is the second as secure as the first?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you intending to encrypt all traffic on the channel subsequent to the authentication?  If not, MitM has some pretty serious consequences (e.g., letting an MitM adversary send arbitrary commands).  If you do plan to encrypt all traffic, you've basically set up pre-shared-key nonced channel; the security properties of this will depend on which mode of AES you choose (and how you check the integrity of what you decrypt), how your messaging is framed/structured, and how you respond to error cases. (And Gray is correct about repudiation, if that is a property you need)

Answer (score 2):

I am not a crypto expert (shout out to https://crypto.stackexchange.com), but AES is meant to assure confidentiality, and your method does not prevent non-repudiation.  In other words, I can't read the contents of the token, but I can intercept your message and send the same one to the server to "authenticate" myself, right? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack) Additionally, someone in the middle could modify your message and potentially cause problems, since again, AES assures confidentiality, but not integrity of the message. Aside from those core issues, there are subtle mistakes you can make when implementing this that can cause issues that are *very* difficult for you (and me) to detect, but possible for attackers to sniff out.

**Perhaps** when combined with an [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC), you can overcome these weaknesses... but I would have to encourage you to not "roll your own" crypto scheme and perhaps all you need is HTTPS to secure the communication between the two devices (and a pre-shared token/key/password to prove identity). If you do decide to continue down this route, I would also encourage you to do significant research and having a security expert review your code/implementation before using in any sort of production environment. If this is just for fun/research, that's another story.

Comment: I think this implementation is not really vulnerable to replay attack, as the token is randomly generated for each connection. To replay the attack, an attacker should listen to the token, listen to the encrypted response, and connect to the server a very large number of times hoping that the token he knows will be generated again.

About integrity, the worst that can happen in case of MITM attack is that the response is stopped or modified, which will cause the server not to recognize the client and therefore not execute the commands. It's not very serious in my case.

Comment: To make it simple, I just want to trigger some bash commands on my server from my computer, without having to connect through SSH. I thought of a Python script that listens on the server side, and that triggers those commands when a client (my computer) connects.

This little "crypto scheme" is just here to prevent any connection (e.g. a port scanner, or an attacker) from triggering those commands.

There must be much more efficient and secure methods to achieve my goal (trigger a script remotely without going through an SSH connection), and I'd be happy to get some advice on this topic.

Comment: SSH is great, why not just use SSH with key-based authentication? (that way you can avoid having to "type" a password).

Comment: @Aeinot  Gray is right..  even your scheme looks valid on the first look, it really may get wrong when not implemented propertly (that's why rolling out own protocols is not the best idea). Using something what is battle proven (ssh, https, 2-way SSL ..) would be much more secure and reliable